# Magento - Validate Mobile No. in Registration Page

Tags: php, magento, mobile, verification, verify

I am designing a website. I want to validate the mobile no. entered by the user on the registration page, by sending a verification code to his mobile phone before submitting the registration form. Can anyone give me pointers to how should I proceed with it?

Comment: You just need to add **validate-digits** class in your input type.

Answer (score -1):

Process:

1. First write some code for validating the entered mobile no.
2. Integrate SMS Gateway by free/paid service providers.
3. Use curl/supported method to send OTP/Verification code through integrated SMS gateway.
4. Store the code on your end and ask the user to enter the received verification code.
5. If the above matches then its validated if not then ask/resend verification code again.

Comment: Need specific answer how to proceed step by step with file names and raw code structure

Comment: So we don't work on 'Make A Wish', try to see plugins/extensions of magento